# bash/sed - Search a line, change it and copy it below the found line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am searching for an easy method to change several lines in one file, edit them and copy them under the found line.

Example before editing:

```
...
#-#parents     hostnamexy
...
...
#-#parents     hostnameyz
...
```

Example how it should be after editing:

```
...
#-#parents     hostnamexy
_parents       hostnamexy
...
...
#-#parents     hostnameyz
_parents       hostnameyz
...
```

I don't want to write a big shell script to do that and thought it could be possible with sed?

Thanks for your help!!

Greets Matze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/#-#parents/{p;s/#-#/_/;}'
```

All string are printed, but when we have `#-#parents`, this prints that string, then makes the substitution. The auto-print takes care of emitting the fixed version.

IHTH.

Comment: There is one extra `p`, use `sed '/#-#parents/{p;s/#-#/_/;}'`

Comment: yes, that is what I needed to test, Fixed now, and thanks very much for your 2nd-set-of-eyes!

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Works great. You saved me a LOT of time with that. Thank you!!

Comment: @matze502 : Glad that helped and glad that you included required output from sample input. (That is the key to getting quick help here on S.O.) good luck and keep posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '7;sub(/^#-#parents/,"_parents")' file
```

this line may work.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '1;/Searchterm/{print "whatever you want"}' file
```

for your exact input and output

```
awk '1;/hostname/{print "_parents\t"$2 }' file
```